# telegram bot get reply message from user

Tags: php, telegram-bot

i have following code :

```
define('API_KEY','*********************');
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$text = $update->message->text;
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;
$message_id = $update->callback_query->message->message_id;
$reply = $update->message->reply_to_message->text;
$rpto = $update->message->reply_to_message->forward_from->id;
$nowdate = date("Y-m-d");

function coding($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}
```

and :

```
if ($text == "name") {
  coding('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
    'message_id'=>$message_id,
    'text'=> "Your Name :",
    'parse_mode'=>'html',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode(['force_reply' => true,'selective' => false])
  ]);
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users_details (chat_id,date,name) VALUES ('$chat_id','$nowdate','$reply')"); 
}
```

and it works fine i want to ask a question from user and then get her answer from reply and stored in the DB, but it sounds like that `$reply` don't get the user message so do I do it wrong?

Comment: What body are you sending to your PHP file? And where is `coding` called?

Comment: @JonStirling thanks for your quick answer i update my question.

Comment: So we're back to what body are you sending your PHP file?

Comment: @JonStirling no, that's okay, I update my code I write them wrong here because my project code's are huge and i just put some of theme here, its works and store date and chat id data in my DB and just show name field as empty in DB.

Comment: Is this working or not then. `$reply` comes from the HTTP request body you're sending, not anything to do with Telegram as far as I can tell.

Comment: so you tell that `$update->message->reply_to_message->text;` is wrong and dont get the reply message?

Comment: I don't know because you still haven't told us what you're sending in the request...

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` is getting the content of the request body you're sending to your PHP file. If you were intending to get that data from the response from telegram, then yes, completely not what you've written.

Comment: yes i intending to get data from telegram so if `$reply` is wrong whats the right way to get reply message?

Comment: I can't because I can't work out what you're trying to do. You say `$update` is meant to be from telegram, but that means that `$chat_id` should have come from telegram, but you need it for your telegram request... so frankly I have no idea what you're really trying to do.